# How to set-up a cron job for multiple models in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I'm trying to set-up a cron job for multiple models. I have two methods (method1 and method2) in Model (observer.php) for which I want to set cron job. My code :

**Config.xml file :**

```
 <crontab>
        <jobs>            
        <erpbridge_update>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>erpbridge/observer::method1</model>
            </run>

        </erpbridge_update>  
        <mss_erpbridge>
                <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
                <run>
            <model>erpbridge/observer::method2</model>
            </run>
            </mss_erpbridge>

        </jobs>
    </crontab>
```

Name space is Mss and  module name is Erpbridge, Cron job with the right module name working perfectly `<mss_erpbridge>` but this is not working `</erpbridge_update>`. When I set the same key for both `<mss_erpbridge>` then only the second works.

**My query :**

Is it possible to set a cron job for multiple Models if yes, How?

Comment: Your syntax is correct, are you sure the problem is not elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Deepak,  may be at any xml file you have using `erpbridge`_update name  cronjob.

I suggest to you use  `any another name for cronjob  identofier event name`.

As magento save the `cronjob idenfier` in   cronjob table at db and basic of this table magento cronjob is excute. So, you cannot use name idenfier name for two cronjob.

For example from app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml:

```
<config>
...
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <catalogrule_apply_all> <!-- this is  indentifier name which is save at db -->
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>catalogrule/observer::dailyCatalogUpdate</model></run>
            </catalogrule_apply_all>
        </jobs>
...
    </crontab>
...
</config>
```

Comment: I tried using different name, but having same issue.

Comment: I have one query, can we use any unique key "<catalogrule_apply_all>" for this  of just "<modulename/model>" name?